# Private variables in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables, getter-setter, accessor

The cocoa Dev tutorial states that all instance variables are private when declared

> Accessors
>
> All instance variables are private in Objective-C by default, so you
> should use accessors to get and set values in most cases. There are
> two syntaxes. This is the traditional 1.x syntax:
>
> ```
> [photo setCaption:@"Day at the Beach"];
> output = [photo caption];
> ```
>
> The code on the second line is not reading the instance variable
> directly. It's actually calling a method named caption. In most cases,
> you don't add the "get" prefix to getters in Objective-C.

Wouldn't it be easier not to need accessors every time you wanted the value? Why are they automatically declared private?

Comment: They are private by default.  This is pretty common among all programming languages that I'm aware of for instance variables to be protected or private by default.

Comment: @HotLicks Really?  Are there programming languages for which instance variables are public by default?  I don't think he's asking about `@property` declarations.

Comment: "Wouldn't it be easier not to need accessors every time you wanted the value?" - maybe it would be "easier", but in most cases, it would simply be incorrect (think about key-value observation, ownership questions of strong pointers, etc.). Also, if there were only public instance variables, you would have to expose all of your implementation details to the outside world.

Comment: I am siting beside a Python developer who is offended by @nhgrif. :P

Comment: C++, for example, has both `struct` and `class`, which are for all intents and purposes identical concepts, except that `struct` members are public by default and `class` members are private.  Java and Objective-C do not have a `struct` equivalent.

Comment: @HotLicks Objective-C is a strict superset of C. It does have a `struct` of which the members are public (unconditionally). Also, `@public` works for Objective-C objects.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - Objective-C's class scheme does not include structs.  You cannot, eg, put structs in an NSArray.

Comment: You can't use Objective-C objects as members of a `struct` unless you're not using ARC.

Comment: @nhgrif I didn't assert the opposite.

Comment: @HotLicks And? The fact that you can't put a `struct` in an NSArray doesn't mean that there's no `struct` in Objective-C.

Comment: (The OP has a valid question -- why are data members of an Objective-C class private rather than public by default.  The answer, of course, is "because".  The reasoning behind "because" is the religious argument.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant You did though.  HotLicks pointed out that Java and Objective-C do not have a `struct` equivalent (to what you'd find in C++).  You disagreed with him, but your disagreement is wrong.  You can't do with an Objective-C `struct` what you could do with a C++ `struct`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - It means that structs might as well not be there, except in very special cases.  There is no struct equivalent that is on par with an Objective-C class.

Comment: @HotLicks (on the side: how about a struct like `struct Foo { Class isa; ... };`?)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant - Yeah, right.  That'll be bug-free.

Comment: And now we know why opinion-based questions ought to be closed extraordinarily quickly.

Comment: I was looking for reason more that opinion, but I suppose that the fact that there is so much opinion is because there isn't a good definitive reason.

Comment: It was a good question -- don't know why the downvote.  Just your bad luck that it's religious issue.

Comment: Editing old questions with brand new questions is not okay; you've received an answer that your edit would invalidate. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: @Zoe I was following the Stack Overflow recommendations, "Begin by fixing your existing answers; do not just post the same answer again or delete all of your existing answers. "

Comment: So I can't post questions, and I can't edit my current questions? What am I supposed to do - stop using the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wouldn't it be easier not to need accessors every time you wanted the value?

Maybe it would be "easier", but in most cases, it would simply be incorrect.

Setters are a better example, but there's a need arising from the use of object-returning getters as well. The typical (autogenerated) implementation of such a getter is equivalent with something like

```
- (Foo *)foo {
    return [[_foo retain] autorelease];
}
```

which is not a coincidence -- if you simply poked around with the object's instance variable directly, then as soon as the containing object is deallocated, its instance variable would be deallocated as well, so it would be an error to use a property of an object after its deallocation.

With setters, the list of problems is even longer. Again, there's the problem of ownership: a typical setter does something like

```
- (void)setFoo:(Foo *)newFoo {
    [newFoo retain];
    [_foo release];
    _foo = newFoo;
}
```

Again, if you were messing with the ivar directly, you would either simply leak memory or would need to keep track of ownership manually, explicitly, which violates DRY (and is vastly error-prone).

Then, key-value observation couldn't work either. If you just change the pointer inside the object, the registered observers wouldn't be informed of that. It's the responsibility of the setter (among others) to dispatch the appropriate key-value observer messages when a property is changed.

Comment: This answer isn't very relevant to anyone using ARC... which is probably most Objective-C developers, right?

Comment: @nhgrif why wouldn't it be relevant to anyone using ARC?

Comment: Because ARC won't let you use `retain`, `release` or `autorelease`?  Even if you're directly accessing the instance variable, you don't need any of this memory management code with ARC...

Comment: @nhgrif yeah, but the code in the answer is not **actual code one would write,** but something that demonstrates how the autogenerated setters and getters work. These methods do the same thing even under ARC, and yet probably you wouldn't find anywhere their implementation like this since the compiler directly generates equivalent LLVM IR and/or assembly code... Also, the exposure of implementation and key-value observing is still absolutely relevant, even if you completely disregard memory management.

Comment: The point I'm making though is that this `retain`, `release`, and `autoretain` still isn't a problem when we're accessing the instance variables directly with ARC.  You warn that we might cause a memory leak... but touching the variables directly doesn't make that any more likely than it would going through accessors...

Comment: @nhgrif I realize. However, it's *still* worth pointing out the MRC case (and KVO, and...).

Comment: Would you see the automatic private variable setting changing now that ARC does easy memory management automatically if(when?) they release Objective-C 3.0?

Comment: @PerplexingPies I don't like to get into predictions, but I don't think that it's gonna happen. As you can see, it's not only about memory management, but also encapsulation, information hiding and single-resposibility. ARC is not in itself enough of a reason to justify such a decision.

Comment: Alright, thank you for going out on a shaky limb anyway :-)

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not easier, in fact the syntax is similar.

```
self->_caption;
_caption; // here self-> is implicit.
```

vs.

```
[self caption];
self.caption;
```

I don't think it's an accurate statement to say direct access to ivars is easier than accessors.

---

The reason for accessors is the abstraction. It's possible subclass and replace the functionality of the accessor. It's possible to refactor the internals, but leave the same interface with an accessor. Accessors are more flexible and more functional than direct access to ivars.

Comment: This ignores the fact that a private instance variable requires the developer to write a setter/getter.  Syntax may not make it any easier... but a private variable means you need to implement more methods.

Comment: @nhgrif I updated my answer to make my point clearer.

Comment: I removed the downvote.  The "No, it's not easier" still bothers me though.  Perhaps "No, it's not easier because we can just use `@property` and get the ease of a public variable plus the abstraction of private instance variables"?